# How to center the page in a browser with firefox

Tags: html, css

How can I center the page in my firefox browser?

[image: Screen shot]

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}

body {
    background-color:#333333;
}

#wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    width:1000px;
    height:1706px;
    background-color: #999;
}
```

Comment: Your code must work, show html too.

Comment: Your wrapper is centered, just add # or . before 'wrapper' (.wrapper if its a class, #wrapper if its an id) and it should work like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74yf84aL/ ... edit: ok, after the edit of the question it seems to be an ID, the centering woks also in firefox for me

Comment: post some of you html source for more help...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the page content is wrapped in an element which doesn't have the `margin` set to `auto` and its `width` defined as its container. This, assuming you actually have another element within this container: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/ho476yk5/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}

body {
background-color:#333333;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width:1000px;
    background-color: #999;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference, apart from the fact that you set `top` and `bottom` margins to 0?

Comment: @MelanciaUK Added overflow management and deleted `height`. Shouldn't fix the problem imo.

Comment: What's the influence of `height` on centering a page horizontally? I don't get it.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
body{
width:100%;
}

#wrapper{
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VerdeletG/at8pe063/

on the fiddle width is 100px for the wrapper and a height is implemented for demonstration purposes!

if a parent element has a set width, the child element's margins automate within the parent class in order to center itself automatically depending on the child element's width. hope this is what you're looking for!